# Add, commit and push single file to multiple git repos

Tags: git

I am in a situation wherein I need to add, commit and push 1 common file to 200+ repos. If this particular file already exists, I would like it to be replaced with new file that I am adding. Is there a easier way of doing it? 
Will this work:

```sh
for i in */.git; do  
(echo $i; cd $i/..; git checkout master && git add properties.txt && git commit -m "Add Properties file" && git push origin master;);
done
```

Comment: If you have a file being shared in that many places you should really consider extracting to a submodule or some sort of package.